# Change \citet{CITEKEY} to {\renewcommand\&{and}\citet{CITEKEY}} globally?

Tags: citing, natbib

As the title states, I would like to use `\citet{CITEKEY}` throughout the document, but wrap it globally in the preamble as `\renewcommand\&{and}\citet{CITEKEY}}`. That way I can turn on/off the "and" in text citations.

Thank you.

Here is the MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
author = {Authorone, One and Authortwo, Two},
title = {{Title goes here.}},
journal = {Journal of MWE},
year = {1991},
volume = {11},
number = {22},
pages = {303--340},
\end{filecontents*}

%========  ========%

\documentclass[authoryear,review,11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\section*{In text citations}

In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet{key}. Note the ``\&''.

This command \verb|{\renewcommand\&{and}\citet{key}}| prints {\renewcommand\&{and}\citet{key}}. Note the ``and''.

I want to define \verb|\citet| as \verb|{\renewcommand\&{and}\citet{key}}| globally, maybe in the preamble, so I don't have to write \verb|{\renewcommand\&{and}\citet{key}}| in the text in order to get ``and''.

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give us a minimal document which shows how you would produce the output you want. Then explain how exactly you would like to produce that output. Right now, I have essentially no idea what your set-up looks like or what you are trying to ask. What does the "and" have to do with redefining the `tabular/array` delimiter? And what does either have to do with text citations? Or maybe `\&` is just a really badly chosen example of a command name? What are you trying to redefine? I'm really confused!

Comment: The '\citet' from the class I use prints "Author1 & Author2 (1990)" - note the "&". Bit if I wrap \citet in the command I've given above it prints "Author1 and Author2 (1990)" - note "and". The problem is I have to do this for each '\citet' in the text. Hence, I would like to define it globally within the file.

Comment: So give us code for a minimal document showing what you do. 'The class I use' is not very helpful. You need to post a [MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).

Comment: @cfr - does the example help?

Comment: @Gaijin: The `.bib` file has errors in it

Comment: @Christian `&` usually is not active

Comment: @Christian it still isn't active (catcode 13). It's the alignment character (catcode 4)

Comment: @Mico, ChristianHupfer's code worked great as well in pdflatex with bibtex. Why did you erase it?

Comment: I did *not* erase @ChristianHupfer's answer.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry then. I may got  it wrong. Anyway, it worked nicely, would love to see it back - if ChristianHupfer's reading this.

Comment: @Gaijin: I deleted my answer -- other users (apart from moderators) can only cast a `deletion` vote, but not delete other posts than their own.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer got it. I'm still pretty new on this forum, still learning the platform. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Mico: You did only stole the tick :-(((((((((((((((((  /sob

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Sorry about that! FWIW, I did upvote your answer. :-)

Comment: @Mico: I know it was you ;-) (Well, I suspected you rather :-P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. The code handles "unstarred" and "starred" variants of the `\cite`, `\citet`, and `\citep` directives with zero, one, or two optional arguments in square brackets.

The code doesn't actually modify the `\cite`, `\citet`, and `\citep` macros; instead, it scans the input file at a very early stage of processing and encases all instances of `\cite`, `\citet`, and `\citep` (with or without a "star", with or without optional arguments) in `{\renewcommand\&{and} ... }` "wrappers".

To make it work in your file, just add the code block from `\usepackage{luacode}` to `\end{luacode}` to your preamble -- and, of course, use LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX to compile your tex file.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[authoryear,review,11pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
author = {Authorone, One and Authortwo, Two},
title  = {Title goes here},
journal= {Journal of MWE},
year   = {1991},
volume = {11},
number = {22},
pages  = {303--340},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function replace_ampersand ( line )
  line = string.gsub ( line, "\\cite[tp]?%*?{.-}", "{\\renewcommand\\&{and}%0}" )
  line = string.gsub ( line, "\\cite[tp]?%*?%[.*%]{.-}", "{\\renewcommand\\&{and}%0}" )
  return line
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", 
    replace_ampersand , "replace_ampersand" )
\end{luacode}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citet{key}

\cite[][]{key} 

\citep[see][]{key}

\citep[][p.~24]{key}

\citep*[see][p.~24]{key}

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am no `natbib` and `\citet` expert and I don't know too much about the options of `\citet`, but a 'safe' redefining `\citet` requires optional argument handling as well keeping the starred `\citet*` variant:

The redefinition of `\&` (if really needed) should be done in a group, such that `\&` still prints `&` outside of `\citet` usage.

**Edit** Improved version for `\citet[][]{}` and `\citet*[][]{}` way:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
author = {Authorone, One and Authortwo, Two},
title = {{Title goes here.}},
journal = {Journal of MWE},
year = {1991},
volume = {11},
number = {22},
pages = {303--340}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%========  ========%

\documentclass[authoryear,review,11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\orig@citet\citet


\RenewDocumentCommand{\citet}{sO{}O{}m}{%
  {% Extra group
    \renewcommand{\&}{and}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \orig@citet*[#2][#3]{#4}%
    }{%
     \orig@citet[#2][#3]{#4}%
    }%
  }% End of extra group
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section*{In text citations}

In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet{key}. Note the ``and''.

In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet[A][]{key}. Note the ``and''.
In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet[][B]{key}. Note the ``and''.

In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet[A][B]{key}. Note the ``and''.

In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet[A][]{key}. Note the ``and''.

In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet*{key}. Note the ``and''.

In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet*[A][B]{key}. Note the ``and''.

In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet*[A]{key}. Note the ``and''.

In text command \verb|\citet{key}| prints \citet*[][B]{key}. Note the ``and''.

And here are some \verb|&| characters: \&\&\&

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. However, there is one caveat—when `\citet{CITEKEY}` is specified in a form as `\citet[TEXT][TEXT]{CITEKEY}`, the optional text is not displayed... :(